# Laptop won't boot after partition error

Tags: boot

So I tried installing ubuntu mate on an old laptop since I'm still waiting for a new PSU replacement for my rig. I followed a guide on using unetbootin. When i made it to the partition menu on the ubuntu installation I followed a video guide on how to do it but eventually I got an error that the partitions were already in use and asked to reboot . I rebooted and now the laptop won't make it to the bootmenu where I get to select whether to boot in windows or unetbootin. It boots after the manufacturer logo and shows the _ symbol till it auto shut downs itself. Help is very appreciated.
(I have 0 experience with linux and I think I just did something retarded)

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like the installation has failed to correctly install your boot loader (this is GRUB by default).

However before you try the steps I outline below it is worth checking that the installation process has created the correct series of partitions for your Ubuntu install. Sometimes it is better to resize your windows partitions from windows and then install Ubuntu into free space on your HD. This is a guide to resizing and then creating the correct linux partitions http://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-16-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot/, the way to check is to plug your live USB in and boot from that (select the try ubuntu option) and use gParted to examine the partitions.

If you find that all appears to be well partition wise then you can go on to install GRUB from your live USB. The easiest and most reliable way to do this is to use the boot-repair

1. Boot your computer on a Ubuntu live-CD or live-USB.
2. Choose "Try Ubuntu"
3. Connect internet
4. Open a new Terminal, and run:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
5. Then run:

   `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`

   This installs the boot repair tool and should also launch it once installed
6. Run:

   `boot-repair`

   To launch and then follow instructions to run the recommended repair. It will generate a URL which is essentially a log which can be examined if it doesn't work, make a note of this.
7. Reboot and see if it has worked

Just to clarify I have made the assumption you had windows installed on your old laptop and have tried to dual boot, if you haven't then feel free to ignore any references to dual booting.

Comment: I will try after I get a friend of mine to help me with creating the live usb since my main rig is unavailable for me atm :/

Comment: You should already have created one using Unetbootin, a live CD will also work. I presume you used these instructions or similar to produce the installation media (live CD/USB) which you used to install ubuntu. http://unetbootin.github.io/

Comment: I managed to get lubuntu installed now. Thanks for all the help!